# Azure outputs outdated public IP-address

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a Terraform file called azure.tf which is supposed to deploy a Virtual machine to Azure and afterwards SSH to said machine to run an Ansible playbook. The problem is that everytime i run terraform apply, the old public IP-address of the previous vm gets used.

I've got a file called outputs.tf which outputs this IP-address

```
output "public_ip_address" {
  value = data.azurerm_public_ip.my_terraform_public_ip.ip_address
}
```

This Outputs IP address but it seems to be the old IP-adress of the already destroyed resource

```
# Create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "my_terraform_public_ip" {
  name                = "testpublicIP"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

data "azurerm_public_ip" "my_terraform_public_ip" {
  name = azurerm_public_ip.my_terraform_public_ip.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_public_ip.my_terraform_public_ip.resource_group_name
}

# Create Network Security Group and rule
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "my_terraform_nsg" {
  name                = "myNetworkSecurityGroup"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "SSH"
    priority                   = 1001
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

# Create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "my_terraform_nic" {
  name                = "myNIC"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "my_nic_configuration"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.my_terraform_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.my_terraform_public_ip.id
  }
}

# Connect the security group to the network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "example" {
  network_interface_id      = azurerm_network_interface.my_terraform_nic.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.my_terraform_nsg.id
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "my_terraform_vm" {
  name = "myVM"  #abstract away
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.my_terraform_nic.id]
  vm_size = "Standard_DS1_v2" #abstract away


  delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "canonical"         #abstract away
    offer     = "0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal"    #abstract away
    sku       = "20_04-lts"       #abstract away
    version   = "latest"          #abstract away

  }
    storage_os_disk {
    name              = "vm1-osdisk"   #abstract away
    caching           = "ReadWrite"   #abstract away
    create_option     = "FromImage"   #abstract away
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"#abstract away
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"       #abstract away
    admin_username = "testadmin"      #abstract away
  }
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
   provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = ["echo 'Wait until SSH is ready'"]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key =  file(local.private_key_path_Azure)
      host        = data.azurerm_public_ip.my_terraform_public_ip.ip_address
    }
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "ansible-playbook  -i ${data.azurerm_public_ip.my_terraform_public_ip.ip_address}, --private-key ${local.private_key_path_Azure} docker.yaml"
  }
}
```

I've looked at the NIC, public IP, and vm in the portal and they all get assigned the new public IP-adress. So why does the remote-exec use the old one?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A Terraform configuration should typically not contain both a `resource` block and a `data` block referring to the same object, because when you do that it can be hard to explain to Terraform the correct order of operations so that all of the resources end up having the correct data at the end of the run.

Inside your `connection` block (and anywhere else you refer to `data.azurerm_public_ip.my_terraform_public_ip`), you should refer directly to `azurerm_public_ip.my_terraform_public_ip` (the `resource` block) instead. For example:

```
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = file(local.private_key_path_Azure)
      host        = azurerm_public_ip.my_terraform_public_ip.ip_address
    }
```

You can then remove the `data "azurerm_public_ip" "my_terraform_public_ip"` altogether, because it isn't necessary here. A `data` block is for telling Terraform that your configuration depends on an object *managed elsewhere*, but this object is managed directly inside this configuration and so this `data` block is misleading.

Comment: I've maded changes according to your suggestions. The VM gets deployed, it gets assigned the new public IP, but it still connects to the old IP.

Comment: @brokkosnarf Did you run the commands `terraform init` and `terraform apply`? This answer seems pretty promising.

Comment: Can you update your question to show exactly what Terraform showed in its UI when you ran `terraform apply`? I'd like to understand better exactly what changes Terraform is making for you here and in what order.

Answer (score 0):

allocation_method   = "Dynamic" should have been "static"